# Promise inside a forEach and variable references

Tags: javascript, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, promise

I'm trying to make a simple Calendar app using Ionic (Cordova). I want to have a list of calendar events and a button next to each one which allows the user to add the event to his/her calendar or to remove it if it is already there. Also, I have put a button to add all the events to the calendar, for ease of use.

My problem is with using a Promise inside a forEach. Let me start with the code, which is from a Cordova (Ionic) app:

```
addAllEvents() {
  this.events.forEach((event: CalendarEvent, index, array) => {

    Calendar.createEvent(event.title, event.location, event.notes, event.startDate, event.endDate).then(
      (msg) => {
        console.log(msg);
        event.isInCalendar = true;
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );

  });
}
```

What `addAllEvents()` should do is (upon a button being pressed on the page) add all of the CalendarEvents in the events array to the user's Calendar and update the event's isInCalendar property to true. `isInCalendar` is used to decide which button to show next to each event (Add or Remove):

```
<button *ngIf="!event.isInCalendar;" ion-button rounded (click)="addEventToCalendar(i);">Add to calendar</button>
<button *ngIf="event.isInCalendar;" ion-button color="danger" rounded (click)="removeEventFromCalendar(i);">Remove from calendar</button>
```

However, upon execution, `addAllEvents()` only changes the `isInCalendar` property of the last event! (judging by the fact that only the last button changes)

What I suspect is happening is that forEach binds event to each consecutive item in the events array and by the time the Promises returned by Calendar resolve, the event object references the last item in the events array, which means that the Promises are modifying only the last event.

Please help me resolve this confusion!

P.S.

The individual addEventToCalendar() and removeEventFromCalendar() functions are working correctly. Here is their code:

```
addEventToCalendar(index: number) {
    let event = this.events[index];
    Calendar.createEvent(event.title, event.location, event.notes, event.startDate, event.endDate).then(
      (msg) => {
        console.log(msg);
        event.isInCalendar = true;
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }

removeEventFromCalendar(index: number) {
    let event = this.events[index];
    Calendar.deleteEvent(event.title, event.location, event.notes, event.startDate, event.endDate).then(
      (msg) => {
        console.log(msg);
        event.isInCalendar = false;
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: *by the time the Promises returned by Calendar resolve, the event object references the last item in the events array, which means that the Promises are modifying only the last event.* No, this will not happen. The problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you! I was curious whether my "theory" was correct. I hope someone will know what exactly is going on.

Comment: No, `forEach` does not do that. A `for` loop with a `var event` would do that.

Comment: Btw, don't use `forEach` with promises (actually don't use `forEach` at all). Use `Promise.all(array.map(…))` instead.

Comment: I looked at Promise.all and I have a question about it: in my case, what should I return from the map()?

Comment: If `createEvent` returns the event `Promise.all(this.events.map(e => Calendar.createEvent(e.title, e.location, ...))).then(createdEvents => createdEvents.forEach(e => e.isInCalendar = true))`

Comment: createEvent returns a Promise, so this wouldn't work :(

Comment: it's because createEvent returns a promise that it DOES work

Comment: Still, the promise doesn't resolve to the event.